# set parent row when add new record to bindingsource (dataset - parent-child)

Tags: c#, ado.net, dataset, parent-child, master-detail

can someone please help me, how to set parent row when add a new record to bindingsource?
I'm using typed dataset, C# winforms.

my code (add parent and child row):

```
DataRowView drvParent = (DataRowView)bsParent.AddNew()
drvParent.BeginEdit();
drvParent["ID"] = -1;
drvParent["Name"] = "Parent";
drvParent.EndEdit();
DataRowView drvChild = (DataRowView)bsChild.AddNew();
drvChild.BeginEdit();
drvChild["ID"] = -1;
drvChild.Row.SetParentRow(drvParent.Row);
drvChild["Name"] = "Child";
drvChild.EndEdit();
```

then when click Save button:

```
this.Validate();
bsChild.EndEdit();
bsParent.EndEdit();
ParentTableAdapter pAdapter = new ParentTableAdapter();
pAdapter.Update(myDataSet.Parent);
ChildTableAdapter cAdapter = new ChildTableAdapter();
cAdapter.Update(myDataSet.Child);
```

ID Parent in child is null, why? whereas I already set child's parent row.
thanks

Answer (score 1):

I'm currently working through a similar issue. You want to make sure you have the correct DataRelations between your parent/child tables. This would be in the form of a foreign key in this case. Without the foreign key relationship, I think what's happening is you first do your update on the parent table, an ID is generated for the parent, and then the second update on the child tries to update using -1 which is no longer the foreign key. If you setup the foreign key relationship, after the update on the parent table, the child tables foreign key should be populated with the correct ID.